# How to login users through android app using website user registration details that in firebase?

Tags: java, php, firebase, android-studio

So after fill the registration form in my site that data should be go to the same firebase that um use with android app. After that I can be able to login using those registration details through the app. As a new person to android studio and firebase I have no idea how to do that.If anyone can give me a step by step guide for this,it will really help me to continue my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow Google firebase docs.
It's pretty good and step by step

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start

Also you can install firebase assistance to Android studio. It will help you to connect your project with firebase very easily.

You can find out steps for it here
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase.html